# Eject all disks and dmg's with Automator script in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix, shell-script, automator

I have created an Automator Service to eject all disks in Mac OS X.

```
find /dev -name "disk[1-9]" -exec diskutil eject {} \;
```

This works, but I still receive an error message afterwords:

"The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error."

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the script as you say, you would need to post a screenshot of the workflow.  BTW which version of OS X are you running.

Comment: i'm on mavericks thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the command, I get errors about files in `/dev/fd`:

```
$ find /dev -name "disk[1-9]" -exec diskutil eject {} \;
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/8: Not a directory
```

You don't need find though:

```
diskutil eject /dev/disk[1-9];exit 0
```

`exit 0` makes the script exit without an error if `/dev/disk[1-9]` doesn't match any file.

You might also use a Run AppleScript action like this:

```
tell app "Finder" to eject disks
```

Comment: thank you, diskutil command works, also found these ways as well: find /dev/disk[1-9] -exec diskutil eject {} \; -OR- find /dev -name disk[1-9] -maxdepth 1 -exec diskutil eject {} \;

Comment: also, in this case, 'tell app "Finder" to eject disks' does not work for me since i have some disks mounted i do not want to eject. thx